# UIDocumentInteractionController crash with presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem: method

Tags: objective-c, crash, uidocumentinteraction, uibuttonbaritem

I tried to open a pdf file with the "Open in" menu, but when I create it, the code crash when I call the presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem method

```
UIDocumentInteractionController * controller;
        controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileUrl];
        controller.delegate = self;

        [controller presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:_openInBBItem animated:YES];
```

There is no error message.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to keep a reference on the UIDocumentInteractionController.

.h

```
@property UIDocumentInteractionController* interact;
```

.m

```
_interact = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileUrl];
_interact.delegate = self;
[_interact presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem: _openInBBItem animated:YES];
```